# apt not installing applications correctly - missing executable

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, kde

I'm on Debian 10, KDE.

I'm installing a package with apt and no errors are shown. However when I try to execute the program I get an error re missing executable. E.g.

```
>>> sudo apt install knights
# .... installs knights without error
>>> knights
Unknown command
```

When trying to execute knights via the KDE menu I get the following message:

```
Failed to execute: 'knights -qwindowtitle "Knights"'
Error: Failed to execute child process "knights" (No such file or directory)
```

My $PATH is like this

```
>>> echo $PATH
/bin /usr/bin     # no knights executable is found there
```

A while ago I accidentally removed myself from most groups. I'm member of the following:

```
>>> groups
cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev bluetooth lpadmin scanner mysql vboxusers postgres
```

I tried this with 2 or 3 applications. I also did `apt update / upgrade` and restarted. Nothing helped... where is apt installing the applications into?

Comment: can you please do `updatedb` and then `locate knights` ?

Comment: I had to install 'locate' which funnily enough worked :) For some reason knights is installed in `/usr/games/knights`. Why is this?

Comment: because its a game :-) please have a look https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/games-directory

Comment: Well I guess, yes :) never noticed these directories before.... just strange that it only came up now and that it wasn't on the $PATH.... could it have anything to do with me removing myself from all groups?

Comment: sometimes it is handy to list the files in a package to find out what exactly it did install: dpkg -L knights

Comment: @ruud that was one command I was trying to find before the other solution... thanks for the hint